# How to log someone trying to make sql injection

Tags: php, sql, security, logging, code-injection

There are a lot of ways here to secure your code from SQL injection attack. But what I require is **How to log sql injection attack** so that we can add him(the attacker-user) in the blacklist-users database.

What I need here, is a kind of function which will return true if there's a sql injection.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST['username'])){
// need a function here which will return true if there's
// a sql injection else false
}
?>
```

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: Why do you want to do this? If you properly escape input or use prepared statements, you do not have to care about this at all.

Comment: @Songo I started here scratch minded. Nothing tried so far being a beginner in PHP

Comment: I need a function which can detect if there is a sql injection it will return true else : false.

Comment: How would you even identify in your codes that someone is trying to do SQL-injection. Would you check each field value in every form on your page, basically every page which is open to users?

Comment: *"...I don't have to care about this..."* - you don't have to prevent the injection, but you have to blacklist offenders when it happens? It seems like you *do* have to care about this.

Comment: And if you find a solution, don't write the logs to your database. Someone could drop your log table using SQL injection. They could probably also drop your table full of blacklisted users. Har.

Comment: @RobHruska What i mean with "I don't have to care" is that if someone make any SQL injection I don't have to care because my script has security against that attack. What i want is to make a log of blacklist sql injectors.

Comment: @YousufIqbal - Ah. That's a bit clearer.

Comment: @YousufIqbal your first question on stackoverflow and it already has 5 upvotes! me envy :D

Comment: @Songo That's because I follow the guidelines provided here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask

Comment: @YousufIqbal good thing u read the Question guidelines. However, sometimes people just post "tell me the best way to do..." or "How to..." with no search effort or even trying anything. This just want the magical solution. Other than that, this is a good question indeed that um surprised that nobody asked it before here :D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use [PHP-IDS](https://phpids.org/) to detect security attacks (not just SQL injection) and add custom behavior. In my case I run PHP-IDS at the start of every request. If an issue is detected, I log to the database, return a generic error message to the user and die().

Be warned though that PHP-IDS will not detect all SQL injection issues. It's not possible to do that automatically. You still need to properly handle your queries.

Answer (score 3):

**Edit**: This answer was made before the question was significantly changed. Whilst still valid, it no longer addresses the OP's specific situation.

SQL injection is one of the easiest web application vulnerabilities to remediate. The problem-space of identifiying potential attacks, recording them, and maintaining and managing a user blacklist with usage-denial functionality is a programming exercise that is many many orders of magnitude more complex.

Learn to use `parameterised queries` properly and SQL injection is not something you will ever need to consider. In PHP you can acheive this using the `mysqli` or `PDO` libraries. There's a ton of questions on here that address this and many more tutorials you can reach from googling for "parameterised queries" or "prepared statements"

Answer (score 2):

**Don't** try to cook-up a homegrown solution to a problem as serious as this. Could come back to bite you in the you_know_where.

Instead, try to see from the server logs the kind of queries and requests the users make and take a decision based on that. (for GET reqs). For POST requests, as https://stackoverflow.com/a/10383937/561269 said, you can use it.